# Find records using script in filemaker

Tags: filemaker

E.g i want to find those records whose total is >1000. How to write this in script.I try smthng like these.

```
  Set Variable[$a;Value:1000]
  Enter find mode[]
  setfield[Table:Total;">"&$a]
  PerformFind[]
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Nothing at the outset looks wrong with the script. Try going through step-by-step (either with the Debugger or by disabling all but one line at a time) and make certain that everything looks like it's working as you'd expect.

Comment: How is it not working? Can you describe what it *is* doing?

Comment: Is Total defined as a Number field? Or if it is a calculation, is it defined to return a Number? You might have a text field on your hands.

Comment: Syntax. Check your spaces and colons: `Set Field [Table::Total; ">" & $a]` `Perform Find []` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with:
Enter find mode
Set field [Table:Total; > 1000
Perform Find [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Within a Filemaker script there is a script step "Perform find", which is discribed here:
http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/scripts_ref1.36.74.html
You could specify your search here directly, without having to enter find mode. However, I think you'll have to choose a layout containing the desired fields before.

Comment: Not helpful? It should even be possible to define the search criteria within the script by a variable. Interested how that works? Is this still an issue for you?